# populate content based on list selection in Polymer

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use the application layout "[nav-list-detail](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates/tree/master/nav-list-detail/src)" in Polymer but not sure how to select something from

```
<!-- List -->
<paper-menu class="list" on-iron-activate="_listTap">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}">
    <paper-item><span class="paper-font-body1">{{item}}</span></paper-item>
  </template>
</paper-menu>
```

and have it populate

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="content"></div>
```

My model is

```
<script>
(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'nav-list-detail',

    _computeListWidth: function(isMobile) {
      // when in mobile screen size, make the list be 100% width to cover the whole screen
      return isMobile ? '100%' : '33%';
    },
    _listTap: function() {
      this.$.mainDrawerPanel.closeDrawer();
    },

    properties: {
      items: {
        type: Array,
        notify: true,
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
    this.items = [
        'Item 1',
        'Item 2',
        'Item 3',
        'Item 4',
        'Item 5'
        ]
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

I'm pretty new with Polymer (especially 1.0) so it may be a simple solution that I'm just missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a side menu like that ( notice **on-click="menuSelected"** ):

```
<dom-module id="dmf-menu">
<template>
    <paper-menu>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{modules}}">
            <paper-item on-tap="menuSelected">{{item.name}}</paper-item>
        </template>
    </paper-menu>
</template>
```

You can add **on-tap** on **paper-item** to execute **menuSelected** method.

And then you can use **e.model.item** to access your clicked item model.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        Polymer({
            is: 'nav-list-detail',
            menuSelected: function (e) {
                console.log(e.model.item);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

If you have your items array be an array of objects, you will get your selected object.

From here you can populate it easily to your `<div class="content">`

Answer (score 0):

Use the selected property of the paper-menu:

```
<paper-menu class="list" selected={{selectedItem}} >
```

This adds the `iron-selected` class to the selected paper-item. I am not sure what you mean by "populate the main content". Just put your menu inside the main template tag of your dom-module.

For an initial list you can add the value to your properties:

```
properties: {
  items: {
    type: Array,
    value:  [
         'Item 1',
         'Item 2',
         'Item 3',
         'Item 4',
         'Item 5'
         ],
    notify: true
  }
},
```

Comment: you'll have to forgive my noob-ness but I'm still unclear about when I click on one of the repeated `<paper-item>` how do I know which item so I can populate data in the `<div class="content"></div>`. Eventually my array will be an array of objects which I'll use to build content in that div.